# submitting form using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a script that produces a popup form. When the form is submitted I need to execute another function to submit the data using ajax.
The issue I have is the second function is not triggering. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

I have a button which opens the form:

```
<button id="new-record"  class="buttontext">open form</button>
```

First function which opens the form, this works fine:

```
$( function() {
  var dialog1, form,
  location = $( "#location" ),
  displayfloor = $( "#displayfloor" ),
  res = $( "#res" ),
  allFields = $( [] ).add( location ).add( displayfloor ).add( res );
  dialog1 = $( "#dialog-form1" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    maxHeight: 250,
    height: 250,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
     text: "Cancel",
     click: function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
     }},
     {
     text: "Submit",
     click: function() {
     $('#form1-new-record').submit();
     $(this).dialog("close");
        }}
   ]
});

$( "#new-record" ).button().on( "click", function() {
  dialog1.dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

Second function which submits the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1-new-record").submit(function() {
    var myform = document.getElementById("requestFormData");
    var fd = new FormData(myform );
    $.ajax({
      url: "../insert_new_floor.php",
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (dataofconfirm) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  })
})
```

The form

```
<form  method="" action="../insert_new_floor.php"  name="requestFormData" id="requestFormData">
<input type="text" name="location" id="location"> 
<input type="text" name="floor" id="displayfloor"> 
<input type="text" name="res" id="res">
<input type="button" tabindex="-1" id="dialog-button-form1">
</form>
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying here... is the second function supposed to be submitting the form?

Comment: @Yaakov Ainspan yes, the seconf function should submit the form, or am I doing this wrong.

Comment: You are, writing my answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken about what you're trying to do, you're using the wrong function. First of all, you aren't preventing the default action, as pointed out by Velimir. So add this line to the function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Additionally, you are never submitting the form. You are just capturing the event once it has happened. To trigger a submit, use this:

```
$('form').trigger('submit');
```

So, the final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1-new-record").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myform = document.getElementById("requestFormData");
    var fd = new FormData(myform );
    $.ajax({
      url: "../insert_new_floor.php",
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (dataofconfirm) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  });
  $("#form1-new-record").trigger('submit');
})
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. Iused your code but the form is still not submitting. I am not getting any errors in the console log.

Answer (score -1):

When you submit the form (clicking the submit button), the page reloads, and your javascript starts from the beginning. You need to stop the form from submitting, you can do that with:

`$("#form1-new-record").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /...`